# Where can I find the Product/Model number on my HP Blackbird 002?

Tags: nvidia-geforce

I own a Blackbird 002, which one? I have no idea, and am at a loss about how to find out.

Inside the case, printed into the plastic, it says the "Regulatory Model Number" is CLGYA-0702, but that number doesn't link to anything at [HPs website](https://register.hp.com/americas/flowPage/registration/index.do?execution=e1s1&cc=US&lang=en#). Also, of the two Blackbird 002's that are listed, mine has a different mother board in it (EVGA m/n: 132-CK-NF78-B4).

Recently after updating to [the latest graphics driver](http://www.nvidia.com/object/win8-win7-winvista-32bit-306.23-whql-driver.html), I noticed that one of my grpahics cards (2x Nvidia GeForce 9800 GTs SLI'ed together) was no longer being detected by my computer.

- Running ms32info.exe confirms that it only sees one graphics card.
- Also, switching the graphics cards in their slots, my POST fails because is detects only the card in the auxilary PCI-Express slot, and wants it in the primary slot since (it thinks that) its by itself.

I would really like to troubleshoot the problem with my graphics card as well as update my bios "Pheonix, LTD P08, 9/9/2008" (which I have also found out is out of date, but HP only made custom BIOSes for the Blackbird line, so flashing it with P10 doesn't work). Which all leads me to finding out what my actual model number is, or how to find it, or why it doesn't show up on the HP website.

Edit: What's even more confusing is that when I start to "register the product" and just type in "blackbird" I am then asked to choose from this list:

- HP Blackbird 002-01A Gaming System ›
- HP Blackbird 002-01B Gaming System ›
- HP Blackbird 002-01C Gaming System ›
- HP Blackbird 002-11A Gaming System ›
- HP Blackbird 002-21A Gaming System ›
- HP Blackbird 002-BB5140RP Gaming System ›